# Why I have a different number of terms in word2vec and TFIDF? How I can fix it?

Tags: natural-language-processing, python, word-embedding, word2vec, weights

I need multiply the weigths of terms in TFIDF matrix by the word-embeddings of word2vec matrix but I can't do it because each matrix have a different number of terms. **I am using the same corpus for get both matrix, I don't know why each matrix have a different number of terms
.**

My problem is that I have a matrix TFIDF with the shape `(56096, 15500)` (corresponding to: number of terms, number of documents) and matrix Word2vec with the shape `(300, 56184)` (corresponding to : number of word-embeddings, number of terms).
And I need the same numbers of terms in both matrix.

I use this code for get the matrix of word-embeddings Word2vec:

```
def w2vec_gensim(norm_corpus):
    wpt = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
    tokenized_corpus = [wpt.tokenize(document) for document in norm_corpus]
    # Set values for various parameters
    feature_size = 300
    # Word vector dimensionality
    window_context = 10
    # Context window size
    min_word_count = 1
    # Minimum word count
    sample = 1e-3
    # Downsample setting for frequent words
    w2v_model = word2vec.Word2Vec(tokenized_corpus, size=feature_size, window=window_context, min_count =  min_word_count, sample=sample, iter=100)
    words = list(w2v_model.wv.vocab)
    vectors=[]
    for w in words:
        vectors.append(w2v_model[w].tolist())
    embedding_matrix= np.array(vectors)
    embedding_matrix= embedding_matrix.T
    print(embedding_matrix.shape)

    return embedding_matrix
```

And this code for get the TFIDF matrix:

```
tv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1., norm='l2', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True)


def matriz_tf_idf(datos, tv):
    tv_matrix = tv.fit_transform(datos)
    tv_matrix = tv_matrix.toarray()
    tv_matrix = tv_matrix.T
    return tv_matrix
```

And I need the same number of terms in each matrix. For example, if I have 56096 terms in TFIDF, I need the same number in embeddings matrix, I mean matrix TFIDF with the shape `(56096, 1550)` and matrix of embeddings Word2vec with the shape `(300, 56096)`. How I can get the same number of terms in both matrix? 
Because I can't delete without more data, due to I need the multiplication to make sense because my goal is to get the embeddings from the documents.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that TFIDF is cutting out around 90 terms.

Since you aren't using the `min_df` or `max_df` parameters and as far as I can tell you aren't doing any stemming/lemmatization, the only difference I can see between the two methods is the tokenizer.

There are two things I'd try out if I were you:

1. Try explicitly converting the word2vec corpus to lowercase. `TfidfVectorizer` does this by default and I can't see where you're doing it in the word2vec pipeline. Ignore this if your corpus is already lowercased.
2. Try using the `nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()` with the `TfidfVectorizer`. You can do this like this:

```
wpt = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
tv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1., norm='l2', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True,
                     tokenizer=wpt.tokenize)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to do the second thing for fix it.